# Recursively call an API with variable in the URL

Tags: python, json, api

I need to call an API: https://api.application/v3/groups/something/members. This will return me multiple objects like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "905191",
            "username": "user1",
            "href": "https://api.application/v3/groups/something/members/905191"
        },
        {
            "id": "1010632",
            "username": "user2",
            "href": "https://api.application/v3/groups/something/members/1010632"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I need to call each of the href APIs and save the data to Excel. How do I call each of the URLs?
I only know how to query the first API and get the full list of IDs, or href, what to do further ?

```
import requests
import csv
import json

client = requests.session()

headers = {
    "Authorization": "bearer %s" % "mine",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

HOST = "https://api.application"
ENDPOINT = "/v3/groups/something/members/"

uri = "%s%s" % (HOST, ENDPOINT)

response = client.get(uri, headers=headers)
response_json = response.json()
paginated = [response_json]

while 'next' in response.links:
    response = client.get(response.links['next']['url'], headers=headers)
    paginated.append(response.json())

print(paginated)
```

Comment: You need to parse data and access the href, then you make a request to href value just you did as your first call..

request -> data[0].href
request -> data[1].href

If you don't know how many items in the list returned from the first request, you need to iterate the items in the data list

Note: also please last bracket should be square bracket

Comment: Maybe just a for loop like 'for i in a["data"]:' with the body 'print(i["href"])' to get the 'href' attribute of the element and make a request to that endpoint

Comment: Also there are many tasks in your question. Please try to divide them and try to execute. Like api call, receiving list of items from api call, accessing list items after api call, saving as csv etc. Divide your problems and try to conquer separately

Comment: thanks for the advises, I will try myself... I've edited my initial post and added the code I used until now

Comment: Btw. your Json in your Question is not valid. The List is never closed. Instead there is an closing '}' which was never opened

Comment: yes, there is a '{' before "data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def call(link):
    links, data = helper_get_hrefs_and_data(link)
    cache[link] = data
    if not links:  # Redundant
        return
    for link in links:
        if link in cache.keys():
            continue
        call(link)
```

Please note that the natural end to this is either a) at a certain point, the links stop pointing to new links, or b) you've trawled everything on the site. This could lead to a stack overflow, so you may want to consider using a stack instead of recursion:

```
    def stack(link):
            urls_to_access = [link]
            while len(urls_to_access) > 0:
                curr_link = urls_to_access.pop()  # Also removes link
                links, data = helper_get_hrefs_and_data(curr_link)
                cache[curr_link] = data
                urls_to_access.extend([link for link in links if link not in cache.keys()])
```

This I think is a lot cleaner. I couldn't test this, as I don't have access to your API.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tommy.
In the end, I've done it this way:

uri = "%s%s" % (HOST, SURVEY_LIST_ENDPOINT)

response = client.get(uri, headers=headers)
response_json = response.json()
response_length = len(response_json['data'])

print(response_length)

for i in range(response_length):
    link = (response_json['data'][i]['href'])
    response1 = client.get(link, headers=headers)
    json_string = response1.json()
    print(json_string)